# Send zip file as form-data in POST request

Tags: go, zip, http-post, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a zip file in POST request body as form-data in GO. So, it is supposed to be in a key-value format. I am able to achieve the same while sending an unzipped file. Here is the snippet,

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
multiPartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
part, err := multiPartWriter.CreateFormFile("File", fileName)
```

However, when it comes to zipping it, I am able to find this,

```
zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)
zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(fileName)
```

Unlike multipart.Writer, in case of zip.Writer I can't find any option to create form file in a key-value fashion.

How can I achieve this for zip as well?

Code snippet[updated],

```
    func SendPostRequest(url string, content []byte, fileName string, 
     doZip bool)(*http.Response, error) {
    
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        multiPartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
        part, _ := multiPartWriter.CreateFormFile("File", fileName)
        
            if doZip {
                zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(part)
                zipFile, _ := zipWriter.Create(fileName)
                zipFile.Write(content)
                zipWriter.Close()
            } else {
                part.Write(content)
                multiPartWriter.Close()
                
            }
            request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, buf)
        
            request.Header.Add(constants.Header_content_type_key, multiPartWriter.FormDataContentType())
        
            client := &http.Client{}
            response, err := client.Do(request)
        return client.Do(request)
     }
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am trying to create a zip file on the fly in-memory and send over in a POST request body.

Comment: @CeriseLimón As the request body only, in form of a form-data, having a specific key string and value as the zip file being created.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Added the 'not-zipping' approach in the main question body. Just trying to achieve the same while zipping.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Hi, I have added the full code snippet above having updates as you suggested. Maybe I am still missing something?

Comment: @CeriseLimón "Are you making a request to a server that expects a multipart form with a part containing a zip file containing one file" - yes.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Apparently it still does not work even after making it multiPartWriter.FormDataContentType() for both. The server, on the other side, expects to fetch it against the key "File", which it can't for the zipped one. It is able to do so for the ELSE part of my code snippet though.

Comment: Both branches of the if statement have a form field name "File".   If the else branch works, then why are trying the zip the file? It looks like the server expects the file, not a zip file containing the file.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Hi, I need to implement a kind of generic solution that works both for zipped and not-zipped file on a need basis.

Comment: You don't need to `new()` a bytes.Buffer.  Just declare a typed variable: `var buf bytes.Buffer` - will work just fine.

Comment: @SandyCash Does not work though. Fails here,
part, _ := multiPartWriter.CreateFormFile("File", fileName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to this one - I am doing a zip of the content byte slice only, when it comes to zipping. Rest are common for both zipped/non-zipped approach. Here are the code snippets,

```
func sendPostRequest(url string, content []byte, projectId string, fileName string, fileType string, doZip bool) (*http.Response, error) {

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("File", fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Invocation of *multipart.Writer.CreateFormFile() failed: " + err.Error())
    }

    content, err = ZipBytes(fileName, content, doZip)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = part.Write(content)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Invocation of io.Writer.Write() failed: " + err.Error())
    }

    if err = writer.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Failed to close *multipart.Writer: " + err.Error())
    }

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, buf)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Failed to create request for Validation API multipart file uploading: " + err.Error())
    }

    request.Header.Add(constants.Header_content_type_key, writer.FormDataContentType())
    request.Header.Add(constants.Project_Id_header_str, projectId)
    request.Header.Add(constants.File_type_header_str, fileType)

    if doZip {
        request.Header.Add(constants.IsZipped_header_str, "true")
    } else {
        request.Header.Add(constants.IsZipped_header_str, "false")
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Failed to invoke Validation API: " + err.Error())

    } else if !strings.Contains(strconv.Itoa(response.StatusCode), "20") {
        respMap, _ := processValidationResponse(response)
        message := fmt.Sprintf("Failed to invoke Validation API with HTTP %s : %s", strconv.Itoa(response.StatusCode), respMap["message"])
        return nil, errors.New(message)
    }

    return response, nil
}

func ZipBytes(fileName string, content []byte, doZip bool) ([]byte, error) {

    if doZip {

        log.Println("Zipped file will be sent for validation")
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)

        zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(fileName)

        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Zip file creation failed: " + err.Error())
        }

        _, err = zipFile.Write(content)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Writing to zip file failed: " + err.Error())
        }

        if err = zipWriter.Close(); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Failed to close zip writer: " + err.Error())
        }

        return buf.Bytes(), nil

    } else {

        log.Println("Normal file will be sent for validation")
        return content, nil

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, I think you'd want to use `multiPartWriter.CreatePart(header)`, where `header` is of type [MIMEHeader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/textproto#MIMEHeader).  `CreatePart()` will return an `io.Writer` - pass *that* to `zip.NewWriter()`:

```go
// Assume you've created your header already
w, err := multiPartWriter.CreatePart(header)
if err != nil {
  // do whatever
}

zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(w)
// Add stuff to zipWriter
```

You might need to play around, YMMV.

Comment: Please see my updated main question body. Should adding ("File", fileName) in MimeHeader do here, since we are trying add them as form-data?